# How can I move a window to another monitor in ratpoison?

Tags: ratpoison

I am using ratpoison on multiple monitors.

Currently, the only I could find to move windows to another monitor, if I first turn off its current monitor (`xrandr --output ... --off`), and then *ctrl/t + num* on the monitor I want to use. However, it is obviously a very sub-optimal solution.

Does a better one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you script it, it's a little cumbersome. But, you don't need to turn off the monitor.

Let's say you have 3 windows: 0,1 & 2 and two monitors: L&R. Currently, you have 0 on L and 1 on R--- you'd like 0 on R.

"C-t 0" will jump the focus to L.   "C-t n" will put a new window (2) on L.  "C-t :nextscreen" will put the focus on R1.

Because 0 is not displayed "C-t 0" will now pull up window 0 onto R.

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! Nice answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

C-t C-Left will move the current window to the left. If the window is the leftmost on your right monitor, it will become the rightmost on your left monitor.